# How to switch current IME using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have created a script to add/remove (toggle) a specific IME. Now, after that IME is added, I want to switch to it, just as if I clicked the language name at the bottom right of the screen, and then clicked that IME on the pop-up list.

I have searched Google for this, but I could not find a suitable command. The top result was `Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride`, but I was not talking about changing the default IME or the precedence; I just want to automate the manual changing as described in the previous paragraph. Is that NOT possible with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shift the IME on or off with ALT + SHIFT in Windows and cycle through the languages. The easiest way to do this is with SendKeys.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%+')
```

This will load the correct assembly and send the ALT+Shift keystroke. A list of special characters for SendKeys can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff731008(v=technet.10)). On my system this changes the language from English to Japanese, a second `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%+')` will then cycle to Scottish Gaelic. Sending a third keystroke cycles back to English.

If the language has multiple inputs like Japanese Hiragana, half width Katakana, full width Katakana, etc... you can use ALT+~ to cycle those as well. Tilde must be escaped. `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('%{~}')`

Note that the application you are attempting to enter text into has to support this though. For example Powershell itself will let me switch to Japanese but will not let me switch to Hiragana, only the standard ascii chars.

I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is but this is one way to shift through your installed languages via hotkeys.

Comment: This is not what I wanted, but this implies "There is no such way" which can also be an answer, so I marked it as the answer. I know I can switch through list of IME's using shortcuts, but this would only work if I had only one IME besides the newly added IME. I already have 3 IME's, and the script is adding a fourth IME. And I do not know what the current IME will be at the time of the script's execution, so sending the shortcut will not work. Maybe I should look for ways to do it with Windows API, and create an EXE for it, and then integrate it into the script, or vice versa.